# How to include library jar in git project

Tags: java, git, maven, jar

We have a core set of java libraries, published as `jar` files, that are used in multiple client projects. Both the library projects and the client projects are on our git server (GitLab EE). Sometimes clients and third-parties (such as sub-contractors) have access to the project source code, but we don't want them to have access to the source for the core java libraries.

So what I need to know is how to set up some kind of dependency or similar in git so that we can automatically pull in the latest version of the library file? I've been looking at `git submodule`, but that looks like it will pull in, or at least give access to, the full source of the library projects. I've also started looking at `Maven`, but I'm unclear whether that also needs access to the whole repository. Is there another/better way to do it? Or will Maven actually do what I want? Or do I need to publish my jar files somewhere else, and if so how can I automate that process, as I don't want to have to manually copy the jar file somewhere every time it's updated (which is often)?

Comment: Maven is exactly what is used for accomplishing this type of task. It manages dependencies in various formats (the most typical is a JAR archive) and ensures that any project with dependencies on some library has them resolved when the application is built. Basically, it searches the "global repository" (most often this is Maven Central, but can be anywhere remote) and downloads the dependent artifacts (jars) to the user's local Maven repo, and Maven handles adding those paths to the classpath when the dependent application is built. No need to source control or see source code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maven and a binary repository like [Nexus](http://www.sonatype.com/nexus) is the common way to do what you're asking. Nexus stores binary files like .jar's .dll's etc and Maven has the capability to publish and retrieve specific versions of these binaries and include them when building the project. As Ryan commented, [Maven Central](http://mvnrepository.com/) is a public binary repository that you could publish to if you wanted the whole world access to your .jars, but with Nexus you have fine grained access control over your binaries.

If you build your own projects with Maven, you can configure it to build, test, and publish right to your Nexus repository with a single command `mvn deploy`. Then clients just have to update their project to point to the new version and Maven will download it and use it on the classpath. It's all very seamless, and I would definitely recommend refactoring your build process to use Maven or a similar product.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification Samuel (and Ryan) - very helpful. Looks like I've got some reading to do around how all this fits together!